# Mongoose sort in populate is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Im trying to get my notifications sorted by descending date order. I believe they are currently coming in ascended order. I've tried two different ways to get the notifications sorted in my populate statement

#### Attempt 1

```
Notification.populate(user.notifications, { path: 'project', model: 'Project', sort: { 'created': -1 }},
                        function(err, notifications) {
                            // console.log('nested population of user', notifications);
                            socket.emit('take notifications', {
                                notifications: notifications,
                                num_unread: unread
                            });
                        });
```

#### Attempt 2

```
Notification.populate(user.notifications, { path: 'project', model: 'Project', sort: { 'created': -1 }},
                        function(err, notifications) {
                            // console.log('nested population of user', notifications);
                            socket.emit('take notifications', {
                                notifications: notifications,
                                num_unread: unread
                            });
                        });
```

I've also tried switching 1 and -1 parameter but this doesn't do anything.

#### Notification Schema

```
var NotificationSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['rfc']
    },
    read: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    from: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    project: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Project'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how that form of `.populate()` works with the `"sort"` option, as that option has a different intended usage.

You basically just want either a regular JavaScript [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) or since the property you want to sort on is already in the parent document before population, then just apply the `.sort()` cursor modifier to the initial `.find()` anyway.

So either in the `.find()` query:

```
Notification.find()
  .populate({ path: 'project', model: 'Project'})
  .sort({ "created": -1 })
  .exec(function(err,notifications) {
      // sorted by cursor
  });
```

Or calling `Model.populate()` on the array content with `Array.sort()`:

```
Notification.populate(
  user.notifications,
  { path: 'project', model: 'Project' },
  function(err,notifications) {
   notifications.sort(function(a,b) { return a.created < b.created });
   // now it's sorted
  }
)
```

So depending on your case, the `.sort()` of the parent items on a present field and not a populated one is either applied by the "cursor" sort or by just sorting the regular array in hand.

---

### The Intended Usage Explanation

Consider the following sample, where this would be "User" model content:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5712ebbc37ba497f25b6b800"),
  "name" : "Bill",
  "sport" : ObjectId("5712e5af18a74c2810d5a5a8"),
  "followers" : [
          ObjectId("5712e001a83d6da651770e27"),
          ObjectId("5712e05da83d6da651770e28"),
          ObjectId("5712e06fa83d6da651770e29")
  ]
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5712ebbc37ba497f25b6b801"),
  "name" : "Ted",
  "sport" : ObjectId("5712e5da18a74c2810d5a5a9"),
  "followers" : [
          ObjectId("5712e001a83d6da651770e27"),
          ObjectId("5712e06fa83d6da651770e29")
  ]
}
```

And then there is the collection with the related "Follower" items:

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("5712e001a83d6da651770e27"), "name": "Fred" },
{ "_id": ObjectId("5712e05da83d6da651770e28"), "name": "Sally" },
{ "_id": ObjectId("5712e06fa83d6da651770e29"), "name": "Abe" }
```

And of course the "Sport" items:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5712e5af18a74c2810d5a5a8"), "name" : "Tennis" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5712e5da18a74c2810d5a5a9"), "name" : "Golf" }
```

The "sort" option of `.populate()` is then intended to work on things like the "followers" content, where when this is populated the items would reflect the order of the "sort" rather than what they occur in sequence within the array before population.

So even if you supplied a "sort" option to both paths to populate, only the "array" content is actually sorted:

```
  User.populate(
    users,
    [
      { "path": "sport", "options": { "sort": { "name": 1 } } },
      { "path": "followers", "options": { "sort": { "name": 1 } } }
    ],
    function(err,users) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(users,undefined,2));
      callback(err);
    }
  );
```

The result would then be:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5712ebbc37ba497f25b6b800",
    "name": "Bill",
    "sport": {
      "_id": "5712e5af18a74c2810d5a5a8",
      "name": "Tennis",
      "__v": 0
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "followers": [
      {
        "_id": "5712e06fa83d6da651770e29",
        "name": "Abe",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5712e001a83d6da651770e27",
        "name": "Fred",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5712e05da83d6da651770e28",
        "name": "Sally",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5712ebbc37ba497f25b6b801",
    "name": "Ted",
    "sport": {
      "_id": "5712e5da18a74c2810d5a5a9",
      "name": "Golf",
      "__v": 0
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "followers": [
      {
        "_id": "5712e06fa83d6da651770e29",
        "name": "Abe",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5712e001a83d6da651770e27",
        "name": "Fred",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

That is the normal behavior, and just as intended. But what you are asking is to "sort" the `users` list returned by a populated property. That is a completely different thing, which is handled by a a regular client `.sort()` on an array:

```
  User.populate(
    users,
    [
      { "path": "sport", "options": { "sort": { "name": 1 } } },
      { "path": "followers", "options": { "sort": { "name": 1 } } }
    ],
    function(err,users) {
      users.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.sport.name > b.sport.name;
      });
      console.log(JSON.stringify(users,undefined,2));
      callback(err);
    }
  );
```

That will in fact actually sort the list just like sorting any regular array. This is how you sort on populated properties since the population actually happens in the client.

---

### Server Side Handling of Lookups and Sort

There may be cases where you actually want this sort to happen on the server. Such things include "paging" results, where it is not efficient to return all of the results to the client API and then just extract the needed page after sorting.

Modern releases of MongoDB from v3.2.x an upwards include the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation pipeline method. This basically does what `.populate()` does on the "client" but instead on the "server".

It does not have all the same options to either filter or directly "sort" items from the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), but since this is implemented in the aggregation framework, those operations can be performed in separate pipeline stages.

Included is a sample listing showing both the handling of `.sort()` in the client using `.populate()` as well as the aggregation pipeline technique with [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

Both come out to the same result, with the difference being that [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) is the technique you would use where the result needs to be sorted before returning to the client API, such as when "paging" data.

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/follower');

var sportSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

var followerSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  sport: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Sport' },
  followers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Follower' }]
});

var Sport = mongoose.model('Sport',sportSchema),
    Follower = mongoose.model('Follower',followerSchema),
    User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);

async.series(
  [
    function(callback) {
      async.each([Sport,Follower,User],function(model,callback) {
        model.remove({},callback);
      },callback);
    },
    function(callback) {
      async.parallel(
        [
          function(callback) {
            Sport.create([
              { "_id": "5712e5af18a74c2810d5a5a8", "name": "Tennis" },
              { "_id": "5712e5da18a74c2810d5a5a9", "name": "Golf" }
            ],callback);
          },
          function(callback) {
            Follower.create([
              { "_id": "5712e001a83d6da651770e27", "name": "Fred" },
              { "_id": "5712e05da83d6da651770e28", "name": "Sally" },
              { "_id": "5712e06fa83d6da651770e29", "name": "Abe" }
            ],callback);
          },
          function(callback) {
            User.create([
              {
                 "name": "Bill",
                 "sport": "5712e5af18a74c2810d5a5a8",
                 "followers": [
                    "5712e001a83d6da651770e27",
                    "5712e05da83d6da651770e28",
                    "5712e06fa83d6da651770e29"
                  ]
              },
              {
                 "name": "Ted",
                 "sport": "5712e5da18a74c2810d5a5a9",
                 "followers": [
                    "5712e001a83d6da651770e27",
                    "5712e06fa83d6da651770e29"
                  ]
              }
            ],callback);
          }
        ],
        callback
      );
    },
    function(callback) {
      console.log("Populate Output");
      User.find().exec(function(err,users) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        User.populate(
          users,
          [
            { "path": "sport", "options": { "sort": { "name": 1 } } },
            { "path": "followers", "options": { "sort": { "name": 1 } } }
          ],
          function(err,users) {
            users.sort(function(a,b) {
              return a.sport.name > b.sport.name;
            });
            console.log(JSON.stringify(users,undefined,2));
            callback(err);
          }
        );
      });
    },
    function(callback) {
      console.log("Aggregate Output");
      User.aggregate(
        [
          { "$lookup": {
            "from": "sports",
            "localField": "sport",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "sport"
          }},
          { "$unwind": "$sport" },
          { "$unwind": "$followers" },
          { "$lookup": {
            "from": "followers",
            "localField": "followers",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "followers"
          }},
          { "$unwind": "$followers" },
          { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "followers.name": 1 } },
          { "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "name": { "$first": "$name" },
            "sport": { "$first": "$sport" },
            "followers": { "$push": "$followers" }
          }},
          { "$sort": { "sport.name": 1 } }
        ],
        function(err,users) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(users,undefined,2));
          callback(err);
        }
      );
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

Output

```
Populate Output
[
  {
    "_id": "5712ebbc37ba497f25b6b801",
    "name": "Ted",
    "sport": {
      "_id": "5712e5da18a74c2810d5a5a9",
      "name": "Golf",
      "__v": 0
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "followers": [
      {
        "_id": "5712e06fa83d6da651770e29",
        "name": "Abe",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5712e001a83d6da651770e27",
        "name": "Fred",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5712ebbc37ba497f25b6b800",
    "name": "Bill",
    "sport": {
      "_id": "5712e5af18a74c2810d5a5a8",
      "name": "Tennis",
      "__v": 0
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "followers": [
      {
        "_id": "5712e06fa83d6da651770e29",
        "name": "Abe",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5712e001a83d6da651770e27",
        "name": "Fred",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5712e05da83d6da651770e28",
        "name": "Sally",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
Aggregate Output
[
  {
    "_id": "5712ebbc37ba497f25b6b801",
    "name": "Ted",
    "sport": {
      "_id": "5712e5da18a74c2810d5a5a9",
      "name": "Golf",
      "__v": 0
    },
    "followers": [
      {
        "_id": "5712e06fa83d6da651770e29",
        "name": "Abe",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5712e001a83d6da651770e27",
        "name": "Fred",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5712ebbc37ba497f25b6b800",
    "name": "Bill",
    "sport": {
      "_id": "5712e5af18a74c2810d5a5a8",
      "name": "Tennis",
      "__v": 0
    },
    "followers": [
      {
        "_id": "5712e06fa83d6da651770e29",
        "name": "Abe",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5712e001a83d6da651770e27",
        "name": "Fred",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5712e05da83d6da651770e28",
        "name": "Sally",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```